# Xcode Import Objective-C, Objective-C++ project into Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, objective-c++

I am trying to integrate this https://github.com/gareth-cross/kalman-ios project with my own Swift project in Xcode.

When building the project I receive 2 errors:

```
kalman-ios/matrix.hpp:28:10: error: 'cmath' file not found

failed to emit precompiled header
'/Users/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Tron-iOS-Bridging-Header-
swift_J9ENU1M0P5CE-clang_M49XZJR5TLTE.pch'
for bridging header '/Users/.../Filter/Tron-iOS-Bridging-Header.h'
```

My project is purely Swift, and the kalman-ios project is a mixture of ObjC and ObjC++.

My bridging header file is:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "KFEstimator.h"
```

For more context, the kalman-ios project is structured as:
KFEstimator.mm makes calls to AttitudeESKF.cpp makes calls to matrix.cpp

My initial thought was the cmath file error was the cause for the bridging header error. But I have almost no experience outside Swift and don't know how to go about fixing it. Up until yesterday, I wasn't even aware that you could use ObjCPP.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I haven't done this in a couple of years, so my knowledge of it may be out of date, but....  I don't know why it's trying to create a ,pch.  Is this related to some specific build step?

Comment: As far as I know, it creates a .pch from the files listed in the bridging header file.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. I was mistaken and believed that the repository was Objective-C making calls to Objective-C++.

It was actually all Objective-C++.

I was able to make direct calls to the Objective-C++ functions by following this [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x6JbiphNS4).